# Store a Fetched row from Cursor in Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

Fetch next from Cursor - > returns the next row from cursor . In Redshift how can I add it to variable or is there any way I can insert fetched cursor data to another table..

and also Is it possible to use for loop in Redshift??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon Redshift supports industry-standard SQL based initially on PostgreSQL 8.0.2. There is no *for loop* in SQL.

In additional, Amazon Redshift supports the creation of [User Defined Functions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/user-defined-functions.html). These are written in Python, which does support a *for loop*. However, UDFs **cannot access the network or read or write to the file system, nor can they call SQL commands (eg SELECT or UPDATE)**. In addition, they return only one value (eg a string or number).

Cursors are [not typically recommended](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/fetch.html) for use on Amazon Redshift.

Comment: for loop in plsql? is plsql available in redshift?

Comment: See [User Defined Functions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/user-defined-functions.html).

Comment: but I can't loop a query in UDF ..its in python

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "loop a query", but as stated, a UDF cannot access data -- it can only used what is passed into the function.

Comment: @KarthicParamasivam In other words, the answer to your question is *No*, you cannot use variables, cursors or loops in Redshift SQL. You will need to either re-write your queries to use only set-based logic without cursors or variables, or you will need a third party external tool to manage the SQL code generation and execution, which can perform looping outside of Redshift.

Answer (score 0):

fyi.. as of v1.0.7562, Redshift is rolling out support for stored procs, with cursors, etc.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_PROCEDURE.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/declare.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_PLpgSQL-statements.html